# BLDC motor don't rotate through the C code flashed nor ST Pilot Motor unless I manually rotate it first

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm using the nucleo-f302r8 + x-nucleo-ihm08m1 + a BLDC motor. I'm trying to make the motor spin on the press of a push-button. I made a C code for it but unfortunately, my motor seems stuck when I press the button. Same thing happens when I use ST Pilot Motor and click on Start. I had to use my hand and help it in order for it to be able to spin on its own.

So the issue is with start-up of the motor, and I don't know how I can fix this. It's like it doesn't have enough strength to start on its own.

What could be the solution?

Comment: What is your motor power source? X-nucleo is a motor driver; what voltage and amperage of supply is attached to it?